# Why does unsigned short (0xffff) print 65,535 and unsigned int (0xffffffff) print -1 in C?

Tags: c

I think the title explains pretty well what I'm asking so here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned short u_short = 0xffff;
unsigned int u_int = 0xffffffff;

int main(){
    
    
    printf("unsigned short = %d\n", u_short);
    printf("unsigned int = %d\n", u_int);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my printout.
[printout picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpIao.png)

Comment: Because you're printing both using the `%d` format specifier for **signed** `int` values.

Comment: Hint: `%d` is for printing _signed_ integers

Comment: [See here for format specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: Cplan, why did code use `"%d"` to print an `unsigned`?

Comment: Cplan, "Why does unsigned short (0xffff) print 65,535" -->0xffff has the decimal value of 65,535.  What output, is not 65535, was expected?

Answer (score 2):

`printf("unsigned int = %d\n", u_int);` is *undefined behavior* (UB) when `u_int` is out of the positive `int` range.  Do not used `"%d"` to print `unsigned`.

Use `printf("unsigned int = %u\n", u_int);`

Comment: I don't think it matters whether the value is in range or not. This matters with `fscanf` according to [§7.21.6.2 ¶10 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10). But, as far as I can tell, `fprintf` does not have this requirement. With `fprintf`, I believe the undefined behavior is only invoked by the conversion specifier not matching the actual argument type, according to [§7.21.6.1 ¶9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel As I read the spec, § 6.5.2.2 6 "one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;" affords the exception.  `fprintf()` does not know the difference when the value is a positive in the `int` range as to if the value was originally `int` or `unsinged`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, that specific provision applies to functions declared without a prototype, which the spec distinguishes from variadic functions.  The spec does not give a general provision for the corresponding behavior of variable arguments to its (very few) standard variadic functions, but for [`f`]`printf` specifically we have paragraph 7.21.6.1/9: "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."  The spec documents the expected types precisely, so formally, I don't think representability of the value matters.

Comment: @chux: Note that we have had [this same argument about your interpretation of §6.5.2.2 ¶6 over a year ago on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254361/struct-iteration-with-without-a-pointer/254387#comment501843_254387).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Curious, have you ever encountered an implementation, even one that used non 2's complement, that not not print an `unsigned` in the positive `int` range as if it was an `int`?

Comment: No I have not, @chux-ReinstateMonica, and the behavior you describe is indeed what I am inclined to expect.  But the language spec does not define it to be so.

Comment: @JohnBollinger With "..  are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined."  hinges on _compatible_ and `fprintf()` has " is not the correct type" hinges on _correct_.  Both allow for interpretation - both narrow and broad as to what is correct and compatible.  In such case where, IMO, the spec offers ambiguity, common practice is a reasonable guiding discriminator.

Comment: I disagree, @chux-ReinstateMonica. Certainly "compatible type" is an explicitly defined concept in the spec, and that is therefore how we should interpret the term in that excerpt.  The "correct type" could be more open to interpretation, but when the spec defines specific types for the corresponding arguments to each directive, I think it's very hard to justify interpreting the spec in any other light.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean that we can't justify relying on behavior in this area that, though not defined by the spec, is exhibited by every known or anticipated implementation.  But if we do, then we should recognize that we are doing so.  Or at bare minimum, if we choose to interpret the spec broadly in this area then we need to acknowledge that others may interpret it narrowly, which amounts to almost the same thing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248239/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-john-bollinger).

Answer (score 2):

This is likely what happened in your C implementation:

- In `printf("unsigned short = %d\n", u_short);`, the `unsigned short` value 65,535 is automatically converted to an `int` with the same value.<sup>1,2</sup>
- The `int` value 65,535 is passed to `printf`, which formats it as “65535” due to the `%d` conversion specification.
- In `printf("unsigned int = %d\n", u_int);`, the `unsigned int` value 4,294,967,295 is passed to `printf`; it is not converted to an `int`. As an `unsigned int`, 4,294,967,295 is represented with 32 one bits.
- Because of the `%d` conversion specification, `printf` seeks an `int` value that was passed as an argument. For this, it finds the bits passed for your `unsigned int`, because an `unsigned int` and an `int` are passed in the same place in your C implementation, so the `printf` looking for an `int` finds the bits in the same place the calling routine put the `unsigned int` bits.<sup>3</sup>
- When interpreted as an `int` type, these bits, 32 ones, represent the value −1.<sup>3</sup> Given the −1 value, `printf` formats it as “-1” due to the `%d` conversion specification.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> In many places in expressions, including arguments corresponding to `...` of a function declaration, values of types narrower than `int` are automatically promoted to `int`, as part of the *integer promotions*.

<sup>2</sup> A C implementation could have an `unsigned short` as wide as an `int`, in which case this conversion would not occur. That is rare these days.

<sup>3</sup> This is a description of what likely happened in your C implementation. The behavior is not defined by the C standard and may vary in other C implementations or even in different programs in your C implementation.

Comment: "That is rare these days." --> With a billon embedded processors per year and many of them using 16-bit `int/unsigned`, not so rare, even in 2022.  Still a good answer.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Thanks, fixed. Actually meant just two references to footnote 3.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` has some anomalies due to the *usual argument promotions*.  In particular, arguments of type `char` and `short` are promoted to `int` when passing them to `printf`.  Usually this is fine, but sometimes it results in surprises like these.  What you get when you promote an unsigned 16-bit `0xffff` to 32 bits is *not* `0xffffffff`.

`printf` has some relatively little-known and relatively rarely-used modifiers to, in effect, undo those promotions and print `char` and `short` arguments as what they "really were".  So you'll see more-consistent results if you tell `printf` that you were actually passing a `short`, like this:

```
printf("unsigned short = %hd\n", u_short);
printf("unsigned int = %d\n", u_int);
```

Now `printf` knows that the argument in the first call was really a `short`, so it treats it as such.  On my machine, this now prints

```
unsigned short = -1
unsigned int = -1
```

(Now, with that said, it's arguably a bad idea to print unsigned integers with `%d`, as the other answers and comments have explained.)